# CLoudingo: SFDC Rest API JSON callout. 400 error returned

Tags: rest-api, rest, cloudingo

The code below is running, i had to pass on the login credentials to Cloudingo because it is/was a stateless REST API call from SFDC to CLoudingo. Have to hardcode the key/password into the SFDC Code.

Thanks for everyone for their pointers. And i will still update the JSON code to create one JSON object to process. Separate i will add SFDC JSONPArser class code to process the response back into a SFDC Case object.

Below is the updated code i updated: Now i works!!!

```
Http http = new Http();
HttpRequest request = new HttpRequest();
request.setEndpoint('https://api.cloudingo.com/rest/CheckRecordForDuplicates');                    
request.setMethod('POST');
//Set the header with the key and password to get access to cloudingo
request.setHeader('CloudingoIntegrationKey','xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx');
request.setHeader('CloudingoIntegrationPassword','yyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy');
request.setHeader('Content-Type','application/json;charset=UTF-8');
//Set the body as a JSON object
request.setBody('{ \n' +  
'    "Fields" : [{  \n'+
'            "Field" : "Name",\n' +
'            "Data" : "Palo Alto Networks"\n'+             
'        }\n'+ 
'    ]  \n'+
'                }   \n'
);
//Parse the entire JSON response
HttpResponse response = http.send(request);
if(response.getStatusCode() != 201) {
    System.debug('The status code returned was not expected: ' +
        response.getStatusCode() + ' ' + response.getStatus());
    System.debug('Response ' + response.getBody());
} else {
    System.debug(response.getBody());
}
```

Comment: Please [format](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/editing-help) the code in your post and explain why you believe this is a Salesforce issue. Doing both of these things will improve your chances of getting a helpful answer.

Comment: Is there a requirement that the JSON in your request needs to be formatted? It should be fine to use a compressed string and it would save yourself the trouble of trying to format the JSON with whitespace and newline characters. Once you've got it working you can leverage the [JSONGenerator class](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_json_jsongenerator.htm) to build these JSON strings dynamically.

Comment: thanks, yes once it's working i will use the JSONgenerator class. This is currently only for small Proof of Concept (POC). Hence i just need the JSON to work, afterwards i can clean it up and use the JSONGenerator class.

Comment: Looking at your current code, you're missing commas in your JSON. Try replacing your setHeader argument with this:

'[{"key":"CloudingoIntegrationKey","value":"f4a56572-030a-4d8c-871f-b1164aaed63f","type":"text"},{"key":"xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx","value":"xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx","type":"text"},{"key":"Content-Type","name":"Content-Type","value":"application/json","type":"text"}]'

Answer (score 0):

A string in Apex code must have a start apostrophe and an end apostrophe:

```
'                    [ { \n'+
```

Note that you also have problems with your JSON (missing commas), and the setHeader method requires two parameters, the key and value. You would not ordinarily put JSON inside an HTTP Header, so I suspect that you're doing something wrong.

Even more to the point, you should **not** be writing JSON this way. It is prone to errors (as I've already pointed out in one example). Instead, use JSON.serialize to create a properly crafted JSON object:

```
String jsonBody = JSON.serialize(
  new Object[] {
    new Map<String, Object> {
      'key' => 'CloudingoIntegrationKey',
      'value' => 'abcd',
      'type' => 'text'
    },
    new Map<String, Object> {
      'key' => 'CloudingoIntegrationPassword',
      'value' => 'abcd',
      'type' => 'text'
    }
  }
);
```

Please check the documentation and make sure it is formatted correctly.

Comment: Thanks you, will process this comment. Initially it was only a small JSON text pass on (call out) but it grew, hence now the JSON object and serialize make sense. FYI, it 's my first coding effort after a long hiatus in coding.